# Is there a way to insert around a character in a regex match?

Tags: python, regex, for-loop, insert, converters

Im converting .m to .py and i want to change the following.

```
for ii = 1:r
    xt(i) = (fr*2-(i+fr-1))
    end
```

to

```
for ii in range(1,r):
    xt(i) = (fr*2-(i+fr-1))
```

So far I got this but cant ignore replacement of **ii** and **r**

```
Replace:  for [a-z]{1,} = 1:
With:  for ??? in range(1,???):
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: You know that for `re.sub` you can create groups in the search regex with `(...)` and can refer to the groups in the replacement string with e.g. `\3` for the third group?

Comment: hey thanks
I got the groups down and can convert it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in case someone comes over this later, I got this to work with the following

```
(\b(for)) (\b[a-z]{1,}) (\B=) (\d{1,})(\b:)(\b[a-z]{1,})
```

replace with

```
$2 $3 in range($5,$7):
```

Comment: You can simplify a bit: Find `\b(for [a-z]+) = (\d+):([a-z]+)` Replace: `$1 in range($2,$3):`